# Zend Framework: Zend_Form in layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

How do I add a Zend_Form to my layout? The layout has no "controller" in which to initiate the form. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to Phil Brown's comment:

```
class My_View_Helper_AddMyForm extend Zend_View_Helper_Abstract()
{
    public function addMyForm() {
        return new My_Form_MyForm();
    }

}
```

Now in your layout:

```
echo $this->addMyForm();
```

I have not tested it, but it should work assuming you have registered My/View/Helper helper path. Less code, and you only call it when you need it.

Comment: I've realised why you would use either controller action helper or view helper. Use the controller action helper if you want to be able to submit and process the form on *any* page. Use the view helper if the form submits to a specific action.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a form to the layout using action helpers.
So your action helper should look like:

```
class Application_Controller_Helper_AddMyForm extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $view = $this->getActionController()->view;
        $form = new Application_Form_MyForm();        
        $view->myForm = $form;
    }
}
```

And this helper should be registered in the Bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initMyActionHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $addMyForm = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('AddMyForm');
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($addMyForm);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to access `myForm` from the layout:

```
echo $this->myForm;
```

Please see more info on implementing re-usable widgets with action helpers in [Weier O'Phinney's blog](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html) and [Rob Allen's blog](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-form-in-your-layout/)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use a view helper over an action helper but the process would be quite similar.

Comment: where would you place an action helper? same folder as view helper?